# Why do I need to use queue<TreeNode**>q and cannot use queue<TreeNode*>q?

Tags: c++

I am moderately new to coding so I would appreciate some help especially when I have no one to ask and only have books and YouTube to consult.

This is my code for a function that makes a binary tree in level order from the given string. I did a lot of trial and error to figure this out.

My question is why does this code only work when the queue contains addresses of pointers i.e. queue is `queue<TreeNode**>q` and not when it is made up of pointers i.e. `queue<TreeNode*>q`.

**NOTE:** While using queue<TreeNode*>q I will obviously use the necessary practices of storing root in it instead of &root.

I feel like the second case (`queue<TreeNode*>q`) should also work since it is pointers and not the actual object being stored. So it should work with the same logic of storing left and right.

```
 TreeNode* deserialize(string data) {
    if(data=="#,"){return {};}
    
    stringstream a(data);
    string temp;
    vector<string>token;
    while(getline(a, temp, ','))
    {token.push_back(temp);}
 
    TreeNode* root=NULL;
    queue<TreeNode**>q;
    q.push(&root);
    for(int i=0;i<token.size();i++)
    {
        if(token[i]!="#")
        {
            (*q.front())=new TreeNode(stoi(token[i]));
            q.push(&(*q.front())->left);
            q.push(&(*q.front())->right);
        }
        q.pop();
    }
    return root;
}
```

};

With the current code and using queue<TreeNode**>q;, what happens essentially is that I am taking a number and storing it in the TreeNode and then pushing that TreeNodes left and right child in the queue. The end result is a connected tree.
When done with queue<TreeNode*>q, the same thing **DOES NOT** result in the nodes connecting.

Comment: Every time you push, you take an extra reference `&`, and every time you pop, you dereference `*`. You created that extra layer of abstraction; that's why the type is the way it is.

Comment: What failed when you tried `queue<TreeNode*>`? Compilation error? Logic error? Output error? It's not like we can look into your mind and see what you tried. (Well, most of us, at least.) Perhaps instead of posting the code that works, you should post the code that does not?

Answer (score 2):

what you have done is, you are pushing the address of root in the queue in line **q.push(&root)** ,instead of only root. That's why it requires double pointer. Refer to the code below:

```
TreeNode* deserialize(string data) {
    if(data=="#,"){return {};}
    
    stringstream a(data);
    string temp;
    vector<string>token;
    while(getline(a, temp, ','))
    {token.push_back(temp);}
 
    TreeNode* root=NULL;
    queue<TreeNode*>q;
    q.push(root);
    for(int i=0;i<token.size();i++)
    {
        if(token[i]!="#")
        {
            (q.front())=new TreeNode(stoi(token[i]));
            q.push(q.front()->left);
            q.push(q.front()->right);
        }
        q.pop();
    }
    return root;
}
};
```

Change these lines also:

```
if(token[i]!="#")
        {
            (*q.front())=new TreeNode(stoi(token[i]));
            q.push(&(*q.front())->left);
            q.push(&(*q.front())->right);
        }
        q.pop();
```

Refer the code above